# Only want to play video from bottom play button video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using a video tag and I only want the video to be played if the play button in the controls bar on the bottom is clicked. I do not want a play button on the video image to show up or be clickable. Is there a way to set this up in a video tag?

```
 <video preload="metadata"   controlsList="nofullscreen nodownload" controls>
    <source src={this.state.video1 + '#t=0.5'} type="video/mp4" />
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H74ve.jpg)